# How to represent an interaction term with three continuous variables?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, interpretation, biostatistics

I built a model estimating the survival probabilities of birds based on 1. PC1 scores, 2. PC2 scores (for both, I have more than 2000 points), and 3. a climate variable (a total of 12 climate variables which represent the different sampling years). I'm particularly interested in the estimation of the interaction between climate and PC1, *and* climate and PC2.

I want to find a way to represent that interaction. I understand that usually, people are [representing the interaction as 2 lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)). If they cross, there is an interaction.

In my model, I have linear and quadratic term which makes it more difficult to see the "lines crosses". If two parabola are crossing, is this considered as an interaction?

I also saw people representing [3d interactions like this](http://www.oliviadaoust.com/from-stata-to-r/).

[This is what I have so far](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByS4UJvxGF-wSjQtWWQzbXB0Rzg/view?usp=sharing). (You can download the file and open it in your browser to see it properly.)

So here are my questions:

1. Does an interaction in 3D is the crossing of surfaces or the way they are warped?
2. How should I represent that interaction so that it's meaningful?
3. Is it more difficult to find mathematically a significant interaction between variables in 3D?

Here is an example I did so far. Does that make sense? Do you think there is a better way to represent that interaction? Does it look like (without looking at the parameter value) there is an interaction?

Comment: why does it matter to you how to represent interactions graphically? the plots are just for you to interpret, mathematically they have no significance.

Comment: Exactly! I want to grasp the importance of the factor I'm estimating. I want to see the fitness function, it's shape, height, etc. (its topography). That's why it is important for me to see the interaction. I want to show how the topology is changing. That's why I'm trying to find how it's done usually. If you have ideas or intuitions on this it would be nice. 

And the question of the mathematical formulation of 3D interaction seems legit to me. I understand for 2D graphs, but does it preform identically when estimated in 3D. What if we have 1000 traits or genotypes? Would it still be good?

Comment: I rarely plot the interactions, and the only time I've done it was with lines and when one variable was categorical. For a linear function, I don't see much value in 3D plots. However, thanks for clarification, this will help you get quality answers.